# Importing modules when you have many directories in project directory(PyCharm) and that directory also has directories

Tags: python, import, module

[The link provided is a screenshot of Pycharm which shows directories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPffY.png)

Path of send_mail.py file - **D:\PyCharm Projects\Exercises\Company Website\send_mail.py**
Path of Contact_Us.py file - **D:\PyCharm Projects\Exercises\Company Website\pages\Contact_Us.py**

Project directory is named as *Exercises*

I want to import send_mail.py file to Contact_Us.py file.
What code should I use to do so?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In python you can use the `..` notation to indicate importing from a higher directory. In this situation, I believe you would use:
`from .. import send_main` in your Contact_Us.py file. For more information on package relative imports, look [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#package-relative-imports). Comment if you have any questions.